# How can I get "go to definition" working in a JUCE project?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ide, code-completion, juce

I'm trying to get "go to definition" working for a JUCE project created with Projucer. I've tried both CLion and Visual Studio Code, but they can't seem to find definitions that live in the JUCE libraries.

I'm on Ubuntu. Is there a blessed path for this? I'm normally a vim user, but I'm willing to try any IDE.

Comment: How is your project setup? CMake? Projucer?

Comment: It's Projucer. It looks like Projucer used to have explicit CLion support, but I guess they got rid of it? If I switched to CMake, would this be smoother?

Comment: I can only speak for macOS and Windows, when using Projucer to generate XCode or Visual Studio projects code inspection works very well. On macOS I use AppCode to work with the project, on windows its Visual Studio. However, most of the time I use a CMake based setup with CLion which, for me, provides an absolute pleasant experience when it comes to code inspection, auto-formatting, refactor and more. Not sure if the same can be applied to Linux, so pardon me if this is not helpful at all :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using [FRUT](https://github.com/McMartin/FRUT) to convert my project from a Projucer project to a CMake project. CLion was able to understand the CMake project, and thus, the "go to definition" and autocomplete features started working.

Answer (score 0):

**I've just figured this out!**

In VS Code go `View` and `Command Palette` and type `C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)` which will take to the IntelliSense Configurations page. Under Include path, on a new line, specify the path to JUCE e.g. `~/JUCE/**`.

> Note: The two stars are needed to tell VS Code to look through subdirectories.

This will create a hidden folder `.vscode` in your project folder with this configuration.

> You will need to repeat these steps for each project you make.

Definitions and code completion should now work.

> To compile your code, in your project folder go `Builds` then `LinuxMakefile` and in a terminal run the command `make`. Finally, go to the `builds` folder and run your project `./exampleProject`.

Comment: I'm not having any luck. I can't seem to even "Go to Definition" on my own functions. Thanks for sharing something that may work for others, though!

Comment: Ohh, you know, it does partially work! I can go to some function definitions, but for a lot of them, the closest I get is "other references results". [VS Code screenshot.](https://smidgeo.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/misc/Screenshot%20from%202021-10-19%2013-43-37.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the JUCE/modules folder to your search path, not the top-level JUCE/ folder!

If you're using the Projucer, you'll also need to add the JuceLibrarySource/ folder to your search path.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).